# Why Can I edit UITextView content by textstograge property if is readonly?

Tags: uitextview, readonly

reading from Apple Documentation for UITextView , I read this for textStorage property

```
The text storage object holding the text displayed in this text view. (read-only)

Declaration

OBJECTIVE-C
@property(nonatomic, readonly, strong) NSTextStorage *textStorage
```

But in my professor's notes

```
[self.body.textStorage
 setAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : sender.backgroundColor}
 range:self.body.selectedRange];
```

How it's possible edit attributes of textStorage if is readonly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property is a pointer to an `NSTextStorage` object. The `readonly` attribute marks the property as read only, in this case it means the pointer cannot be changed.

It does however not say anything about whether the object it points to is mutable or not. So you can edit the current `textStorage` but not replace it with a different `NSTextStorage` object.

Comment: So, value of pointer ( address of memory ) cannot be changed. In your opinion, why it's important that the pointer is read-only?

Comment: It means that the UITextView internally can assume that the textStorage is of a given subclass.

Comment: Uhm... sorry but I don't understand... : /

Comment: The `textStorage` is of class `NSConcreteTextStorage`, a subclass to `NSTextStorage`. Apple can add methods to `NSConcreteTextStorage` and use them in `UITextView`, as they know the text storage is always a `NSConcreteTextStorage`. If instead the `textStorage`-property was readwrite, it might have been replaced with a different `NSTextStorage`-subclass without their methods, making the implementation of `UITextView` much harder.